# Convolution of various functions

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

There is asked in an example to do convolution $ h_1(t)*h_2(t) + h_3(t)*h_4(t) $ where

$h_1(t) = e^{-2t}u(t)$

$h_2(t) = 2e^{-t}u(t) $

$h_3(t) = e^{-3t}u(t) $

$h_4(t) = 4\delta(t) $

and then the answer is written  $ [e^{-t}-e^{-2t}]u(t) + 12e^{-3t}u(t)$.

But for second part 
$$ 
h_3(t)*h_4(t) 
= h_3(t)*4\delta(t) 
= 4h_3(t)*\delta(t) 
= 4h_3(t) =4e^{-3t}u(t)
 $$

as $ x(t)*\delta(t)=x(t) $ and for first part:

as $ u(\tau)u(t-\tau) = 1 $ for $ 0<t<\tau $ and $0$ for otherwise

$$
h_1(t)*h_2(t) = \int_{0}^{t}{e^{-2\tau}2e^{-t+\tau}}d\tau
=2e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\tau}d\tau
=-2e^{-t}[e^{-t}-1]
=-2[e^{-t}-e^{-2t}]
$$

Where am I wrong? How did they get $u(t)$ though we use value for $ u(\tau)u(t-\tau)$?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What is $h_i(t)\ast h_j(t)$? You are probably referring to $(h_i\ast h_j)(t)$, also denoted $h_i\ast h_j(t)$. If you are, please correct your post.

Comment: @Did The first notation is common in signal processing texts.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Is it also common to use $f(t)\ast g(s)$ for $t\ne s$ in these texts? More importantly do you have a source for this assertion?

Comment: @Did Well, I don't have it in front of me, but I'm pretty sure that Oppenheim and Schaeffer use it. As for $t \neq s$, no; I don't see how that would make sense.

Comment: @Did, my notations are correct.It's just an practice example for convolution, so nothing about the source.  This notation is common in signal processing.

Comment: This is unfortunate and probably due to a confusion, at lest in the notations, between the sequence $(x(n))_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ and some term $x(n)$ in this sequence, for some given $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Both $h_1(t)$ and $h_2(t)$ are left-sided signals, therefore their ROC will also be left-sided. We know that the Laplace transform of two signals convolved in time domain is the product of their individual Laplace transform,  and the resulting ROC is (at least) the intersection of their individual ROCs. So, the ROC of $h_1(t) \ast h_2(t)$ is left-sided. Therefore, the time-domain signal $h_1(t) \ast h_2(t)$ has to be left-sided. As a result, after doing the integration, we have to add $u(t)$ to the result to make it left-sided.